# Can react useContext pass value from peer component to peer component（in different file）？

Tags: react-hooks

I only see examples of using useContext to pass values between parent and child components. I want to know if useContext can pass values between sibling components, which come from different files.

Answer (score 1):

You can define context on parent component and then use it in its 2 childs respectively siblings.

You can also use Redux for this